# Awesomium browser new window not working

Tags: html, wpf, windows, webbrowser-control, awesomium

I am using Awesomium  browser control in my wpf application. It loads website from url but I have a problem. My website have some anchor links with target blank. but when I click on that anchor tag nothing happening and its preventing the action. So my question is `Is there  any way to detect if anchor tag with target="_blank" clicked`.
Please give me any advice I have searched on Google but no luck.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to handle ShowCreatedWebView event:

```
    webControl.ShowCreatedWebView += OnShowNewView;

    internal static void OnShowNewView( object sender, ShowCreatedWebViewEventArgs e )
    {
        // Do sth with your link
    }
```

It's all described in awesomium docs [here](http://docs.awesomium.net/?tc=E_Awesomium_Core_IWebView_ShowCreatedWebView)

Btw. If you want to open link in external browser you can use

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(your_link);
```